# Setting up android studio Room database with 2 entities error

Tags: sqlite, android-studio, compiler-errors

after creating the entities and necessary Daos I've set-up the Room database as follows:

```
@Database(entities = {Entity1.class , Entity2.class}, version = 1,exportSchema = false)
public abstract class Database extends RoomDatabase {
 ...
}
```

after trying to build the project I receive the following compilation error:

```
**error: variable _columns is already defined in method onValidateSchema(SupportSQLiteDatabase)**
```

in class: Database_Impl.

my guess is that Room is creating the code for both tables, in the same function, but doesn't distinguish
between the tables variables as he tries to create them.

any insight? what did I do wrong?

I tried:

- restarting android studio.
- clean build.

Comment: I had been using a non-english (Hindi) table name, it was working fine but adding another table (total more than one) caused this issue since generated code forms camel cased variable names for all tables as per their names and unicode is not supported in variable name declarations and was ignored which resulted in common variable names causing this issue.

Comment: The solution was the same to change non-ascii table names to ascii names

Answer (score 0):

the problem was naming the entities not in english.

Comment: That is an answer. Albeit could be phrased better with more detail.